# How to install redisGraph on mac with my existiing redis database

Tags: redis, redisgraph

I have been trying for 2 days to install redisGraph on mac WITH my existing redis database, it can be done with redis cloud but i want to have it locally ( and free ).
I go redis working, but i don't understand, and can't find how to install modules on my mac.
Btw i have a M1 macbook pro (maybe it maters).
Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Did you try to just run it in docker? 
`docker run -p 6379:6379 -it --rm redislabs/redisgraph`

Comment: I have, it works fine, but I wanted to add redisGraph to my existing redis database

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building it locally?
see instructions [here](https://github.com/RedisGraph/redisGraph/#building)

Comment: Yes but I get this error

./util/simple_timer.h:45:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.

I have tried some solutions I saw online like
brew install libomp
But nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler are you using, I'll suggest using GCC, preferably version 10 or 11

Comment: I user GCC, i got it compiling But mac CLANG is a nightmare, i have i error and nothing works.
`./util/simple_timer.h:45:10: fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found
#include <omp.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.`

@SWilly22